# Side-by-side captions in minipage run too long, don't wrap to second line

Tags: floats, captions, minipage

I'm writing some proceedings based on the style guide [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERUCX.png). I have two images which I want to place side-by-side in my article, but when I do, the captions don't wrap onto multiple lines but overlap each other and go off the sides of the page, as you can see in the picture below. I know it's a problem with the style guide because when I change the MWE I've included to `\documentclass{article}` the captions are wrapped properly.

Can someone tell me why this is happening and how to fix it?

```
\documentclass[aPhyssubmission, Phys]{SciPost}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{example-image-a} 
        \label{fig:X17Exclusion}
        \centering
        \caption{My long caption includes some useless test text and is poorly formatted.}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{example-image-a} 
        \label{fig:PADMEX17Scan}
        \caption{My long caption includes some useless test text and is poorly formatted and goes over multiple lines.}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Off-topic: In `figure` and `table` environments, the `\label` instructions must be placed after, not before, the `\caption` directives if you want to be able to cross-reference these objects using the basic LaTeX `\label`-`\ref` mechanism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I've found a copy of `SciPost` document class online at https://git.scipost.org/scipost/SciPost_LaTeX_Templates_Submission.)

The `SciPost` document class loads, among other packages, the `caption` package automatically, with the (to me, at least) somewhat surprising option

```
width=.90\textwidth
```

That's the cause of the caption-related mess you've encountered.

The fix? Assuming the widths of the `minipage` environments inside the `figure` environment are set to `0.45\textwidth`, you could issue the instruction

```
\captionsetup{width=0.45\textwidth}
```

immediately after `\begin{figure}`.

---

[image]

```
\documentclass[aPhyssubmission, Phys]{SciPost}
% This document class loads several packages automatically, including 'caption', 'graphicx', and 'hyperref' 
\hypersetup{colorlinks,allcolors=blue} % optional

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\captionsetup{width=0.45\textwidth} % same as width of minipage environments
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a} 
      \caption{This long caption includes some useless test text and is poorly formatted.}
      \label{fig:X17Exclusion} % note: \label is placed after \caption
    \end{minipage}%
    \hfill % maximize separation between the minipages
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b} 
      \caption{This long caption includes some useless test text, is poorly formatted, and goes over multiple lines.}
      \label{fig:PADMEX17Scan} % note: \label is placed after \caption
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\noindent
Cross-references to figures \ref{fig:X17Exclusion} and \ref{fig:PADMEX17Scan}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: This was extremely helpful, thank you!